# GPPSignIn delegate methods are not getting executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus-signin

I have integrated **Goolge+ signin** to iOS (using ObjC) by following instructions on google website but the delegate methods (i am interested in this method `finishedWithAuth:auth:error`) of `GPPSignIn` are not getting executed. I have to store the access token received in the delegate method in shared preferences.

Here's my code:

`

```
-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"success");
    }
}
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
openURL: (NSURL *)url
sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation: (id)annotation {
    NSLog(@"application");
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
-(void)refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn {
    NSLog(@"refreshInterfaceBasedOnSignIn");
    if ([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]) {
        // The user is signed in.
        self.signInButton.hidden = YES;
        [self readProfileInformation];
        // Perform other actions here, such as showing a sign-out button
        [self readProfileInformation];
        NSLog(@"readProfileInformation");
    } else {
        self.signInButton.hidden = NO;
        // Perform other actions here
    }
}
- (void)disconnect {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
}
- (void)didDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Received error %@", error);
    } else {
        // The user is signed out and disconnected.
        // Clean up user data as specified by the Google+ terms.
    }
}
- (void)signOut {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // google+ code
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    // uncommented to fetch  user email
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    // You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    // Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
    // signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    // uncommented & set to "profile" & "email" scope:
    signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile", @"email" ];
    // Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
    signIn.delegate = self;
    // try silent authentication
    [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
}
@end
```

`

Thanks

Comment: Of course may be you forget to set delegate of GPPSignIn class.

Comment: No, i haven't, have marked `<GPPSignInDelegate>` to delegate. Can anyone suggest me a good example to accomplish this.

Comment: did you add this line    signIn.delegate = self;

Comment: @karthikeyan i already have done it, refer the code above.

Comment: did you check with break point?

try login scope  kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin

Comment: yes i have, still no luck :(

Comment: finally solved :)
By moving application method to AppDelegate.m

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me too in my apps running iOS 8. What did it for me was to set the clientId in the AppDelegate as soon as the app launched, and not in the viewDidLoad method of my UIViewController class as indicated in the Google+ Sign-in for iOS example in the following URL: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
/
//Google+
// Set app's client ID for |GPPSignIn| and |GPPShare|.
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"xxxxxx.......apps.googleusercontent.com";

...

return YES;

}
```

So, in your UIViewController class the sign-in method should be:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Google+ for Logging in the user again if the app has been authorized
signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn trySilentAuthentication];

...
}
```